# Sublime text 2 - how to order a list of words alphabetically (DESC / ASC)

Tags: sorting, sublimetext2, sublimetext, alphabetical-sort

Is there any way to order a huge list of words alphabetically?

for example:

```
Hey
Salcaiser
Ok
Here
Strange
Weird
Gosh
```

**By huge i mean about 500/1000 words (1 word per line)
I'm on Mac osx**

Comment: What do you mean by huge? How many they could be and which platform you are working on?

Comment: @Rashad updated question with additional infos thanks

Comment: Are the words stored in separate lines?

Comment: @Rashad yeah sure, as in the example above

Comment: 500-1000 words is not huge. (I would consider about 10^6 lines as medium and would begin saying "huge" when the file has more than 2GB)

Answer (score 163, accepted):

Once I've found this somewhere. It worked for me.
"For alpha sort, select the lines to be sorted and hit F5. This option ignores capitalization. Hitting Control F5 will sort lines starting with capital letters first, then alphabetize lines starting with lowercase letters."

"The Permute Lines menu options provide a few more ways to sort, including Reverse, which sorts in reverse alpha order, starting with lowercase letters, Unique, which removes duplicated lines, and Shuffle, which sorta kinda randomizes the text."

I think General Redneck's screenshot will help. So I am adding it:

[image]

In v2.0.2 on Windows and Ubuntu shortcut is F9.

Comment: On Mac , it's Ctrl+F5 Sublime Text 2 version 2.0.2

Comment: Figure I would add a[screenshot of the menu](http://content.screencast.com/users/talkitivewizard/folders/Jing/media/fe5cbad7-ac68-4008-b568-8c9282ba8f1d/00000375.png) to show where Permute Lines was.

Comment: I'm using v2.0.2 on Windows and the shortcut is F9

Comment: For Linux and Sublime Text 3 it is also <kbd>F9</kbd> (<- This works in the post and looks very nice. Too bad that it doesn't work in comments).

Comment: Man, the more I use this superb piece of software, the more I love it. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Is there some way to change the sort order? I would like Swedish sorting of åäö  (x>y>z>å>ä>ö)

Answer (score 57):

For those that find this question and have no luck with Rashad's F5 answer, on my copy of Sublime Text 3 the default shortcut to "Sort Lines" is F9 and to "Sort Lines (Case Sensitive)" is Ctrl + F9. See the Edit menu.

I know this doesn't directly answer the question, but I'm hoping that it saves a couple people a few minutes.

[image]

Comment: This was exactly what I was after. :)
Thanks alot

Answer (score 12):

you select the text and: 
In WindowsOS is the key **"f9"** only,
In MacOS keys **fn** + **f5**

Regards

Answer (score 4):

Using sublime 2, found that it's built in. ya so handy I am surprised too.. :D

> { "keys": ["f9"], "command": "sort_lines", "args": {"case_sensitive": false} },

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+f9"], "command": "sort_lines", "args": {"case_sensitive": true} },
```

Just select the lines and hit the shortcut.

Answer (score -1):

You select the text and:

In WindowsOS is the key "f9" only,

In MacOS keys fn + f5

Or you can search on google "Online Tools for Sort Alphabetically" then lots of tools will display on google.